# Too many arguments with IF (another one!)

Tags: worksheet-function, arguments, if

I have a very complex set of arguments. I can get my spreadsheet to partially work but not fully and have to use an additional column and make manual adjustments. If anyone could help me just have a single column that would be brilliant!!

I would like a single column for the status of a project. Currently I use 2.

In the first column 'Current Status' the formula is:

```
=IF(D2="","",IF(D2>TODAY(),"Not due to start",IF(E2="","Due; start not confirmed",IF(G2="","Ongoing",IF(LEFT(C2,3)="Yes","Abandoned / Renounced","Completed")))))
```

In the second column 'Finish Due' the formula is:

```
=IF(F3="","",IF(F3>TODAY(),"",IF(G3="","Due to complete; follow-up needed","")))
```

When I try to incorporate the formula from Column 2 into Column 1, I get the error message of 'too many arguments'. Is there any way around this please?

[image: picture of spreadsheet]

Comment: Not much one can try with a picture, is there?  I would go for a function written in basic.

Comment: How about using additional columns (which you can then hide) to partially calculate the result? That way the formulae for your final cell will be a lot simpler.

Comment: Please edit your post to show the formula giving the error message. Too many arguments probably means you've got more than three arguments in a single `IF()`, which means you've made a mistake while combining them.

Comment: Thank you! I have gone for the hidden additional column option which seems to have worked.